# Open video in full Screen on Samsung video player

Tags: android, video

Is there a way to open videos in full screen mode through an intent on Samsung devices? Samsung video player comes with three different modes to stretch video, and I need that it opens in full screen by default.

I'm using a regular intent for this task:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(uri), "video/*");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Maybe there is an extra that performs this action.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can open any file in an external app with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
MimeTypeMap map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.getName());
String type = map.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
if (type == null)
    type = "*/*";
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

It will automatically choose a app for you from your device, if there is more than one app that can open the file it will ask which one you would like to use.

on my tablet it opens videos in full screen.

Comment: I like the way you get the type! But it didn't work. I'm afraid there is no way to achieve this.

Comment: It worked on my Galaxy tab 2. i opened an mp4 file and it opened fullscreen, when i pressed back it went back to my app.

Answer (score 0):

```
intent.putExtra("force_fullscreen",true);
```

just try this .. it will force to full screen

Comment: This only works if the target app is youtube, but not for Samsung Video player. Thanks anyway!

Comment: No, our solution was to create our own activity with a VideoView. Video gave us some problems on other devices and it was the best way to keep control of everything.